# Java get value of stream used to mapped to another stream

Tags: java, functional-programming, hashmap, java-stream

I am using the following code to create entries to a HashMap and search for the biggest **value** stored. The following snipped works::

```
//key                                                  value
LongStream.rangeClosed( 2 , 1_000_000 ).mapToInt( i -> hm.createAndGet( i) ).max().getAsInt();
```

How could I change it to return the **key** assosiated with the biggest value? In other words, how can I write this loop using streams?

```
//creates entries and searches for the maximum value stored in hm, and returns the key assosiated with the highest value
int maxValue = -1;
long maxKey = -1;
for(long currentKey = maxNum; currentKey > 0; currentKey --)
{
    int currentValue = hm.createAndGet( currentKey );
    if( maxValue < currentValue )
    {
        maxKey = currentKey ;
        maxStart = currStart;
    }
}
return maxKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `max(Comparator)`:

```
long maxKey = LongStream.rangeClosed( 2 , 1_000_000 )
                        .boxed()
                        .max(Comparator.comparingInt( i -> hm.createAndGet( i ) ) )
                        .get();
```

However it's not guaranteed that `createAndGet` will be called only once for every supplied key (actually it will be called twice for the most of the keys).

Alternative solution would be to introduce the stream of pairs like this:

```
long maxKey = LongStream.rangeClosed(2, 1_000_000)
                    .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, hm.createAndGet( i )))
                    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                    .get().getKey();
```

In general Stream API should not be used to produce side-effects in most of the operations (except `peek`, `forEach` and `forEachOrdered`). For example, in your code `mapToInt` method is called with stateful lambda while documentation [explicitly says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.LongToIntFunction-) that the passed function must be stateless.